# Batch file not replacing string if it contains spaces

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm using this script to replace string (containing spaces) in file (it's working if variables doesn't have spaces)

Script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<>" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        if %%a == Salutation (
            powershell -Command "(gc File.txt) -replace '%%b', 'bye' | Out-File -encoding ASCII File.txt"
        )
        if %%a == path (
            powershell -Command "(gc File.txt) -replace '%%b', 'C:\Program File\It worked' | Out-File -encoding ASCII File.txt"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

File:

```
<Salutation>hello</Salutation>
<try>this</try>
<path>C:\Program File\Try Spaces\This</path>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes. `-replace ([regex]::Escape('%%b'))`

Comment: The two `for` loops can be merged together to `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<>" %%a in (File.txt) do (` producing the same output on the sample data in `File.txt` without leading spaces/tabs. But if there is not guaranteed that the XML file never contains leading spaces/tabs, it is better to use the two `for /f` loops with the first one removing the leading spaces/tabs from the line and the second one getting the name and the value of the XML element on current line.

Comment: Please note that the PowerShell command lines search in entire file for `hello` respectively `C:\Program File\Try Spaces\This` and replaces all occurrences with `bye` respectively `C:\Program File\It worked`. It would be most likely better to omit the Windows batch file code and use two regular expression replaces done with PowerShell to modify the values of the two XML elements `Salutation` and `path`. Or the XML file is parsed as XML with changing the two values, see [\[powershell\] XML file change value](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+XML+file+change+value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace() so there's no need to worry about regex expressions.

```
@echo off
rem replace.bat

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<>" %%a in ("%%i") do (
        if %%a == Salutation (
            powershell -Command "(gc File.txt) -replace '%%b', 'bye'"
        )
        if %%a == path (
            powershell -Command "(gc File.txt).replace('%%b', 'C:\Program File\It worked')"
        )
    )
)
```

```
.\replace.bat

<Salutation>bye</Salutation>
<try>this</try>
<path>C:\Program File\Try Spaces\This</path>
<Salutation>hello</Salutation>
<try>this</try>
<path>C:\Program File\It worked</path>
```

Another powershell way.  The xml is invalid without a top node.

```
<doc>
  <Salutation>hello</Salutation>
  <try>this</try>
  <path>C:\Program File\Try Spaces\This</path>
</doc>
```

```
[xml]$xml = get-content file.txt
$xml.doc.Salutation = 'bye'
$xml.doc.path = 'C:\Program File\It worked'
$xml.save("$pwd\file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `batch-file` solution without the use of `Powershell`.

```
@echo off
set "search=Salutation"
set "search2=path"
set "replace=replaced"
set "replace2=C:\Program Files\It Worked"
set "File=File.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%File%" ^& break ^> "%File%" ') do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=%%i"
    for /f "tokens=1-4*delims=><" %%a in ("!line!") do (
         if "%%a" == "%search%" set "line=!line:%%b=%replace%!"
         if "%%b" == "%search%" set "line=!line:%%c=%replace%!"
         if "%%a" == "%search2%" set "line=!line:%%b=%replace2%!"
         if "%%b" == "%search2%" set "line=!line:%%c=%replace2%!"
    )
    >>"%File%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

Unfortunately this now has four `if` statements (two for each search/replace) because of your example input. Typically `xml` format is indented i.e:

```
<tag>
    <Salutation>hello</Salutation>
    <try>this</try>
    <path>C:\Program File\Try Spaces\This</path>
</tag>
```

but that will depend on how the file was saved and how it is read. So the code allows for indented tags as well. If however the file content remains the same for either, you can simply remove the irrelevant `if` statements.